# How to change background color of entire totals row in table view in OBIEE

Tags: obiee

Is it possible to change whole totals row of table view?

The picture shows our table, with grand totals row in the end, as it can be seen formatting is done for labels and measueres and background color is applied. However a cell of the totals row which comes from a dimension column has not been changed. Tried to look at XML code but couldnt find the appropriate section for it.

How can we change it too?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible. The only dimension column that will show the background formatting is the one that is being aggregated by.

For example:
A table with:
|Company|Branch|Department|#FTE|

If you want a grand total for the whole company, you would click on the Sum icon for the Company column, choosing After or Before, and then choosing a format for the Header and Values. Let's say you wanted a Light Green background. At the total row, the Company column will show with a green background, but Branch and Department are gray. I believe this indicates that's not the level being totaled. If you create another total at the Branch level (by clicking the sum icon... let's select light blue as the background for this), you'll see another level of subtotals, with the Branch column as light blue, and Company and Department are gray. You would also see a total row that is light green.

I think it's intentional, to let the user know what column is being aggregated. The rest will always be gray.

I could be wrong... I'm no expert! But that was my experience with my trial and error attempts, and this was my interpretation of it.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for a reply @DataJunkieJanet, unfortunately, I believe you are right, I could not found solution for this and also accepted a fact that it is technically impossible